# How do i can show form data after submit on other page using isolated scope directive?

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

I am new to angularjs,i make a sample app ,now i want to display data on next page when form is submitted using isolated scope directive .
my index.html:

```
 <body ng-controller="mainController">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing Example</a>
  </div>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a>    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
   </nav>
 <div id="main">
    <!-- angular templating -->
    <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
   <div ui-view></div>
</div>
</body>
```

**Directive:**

```
  var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp');

  scotchApp.directive('homeData', function() {
   return {
      scope: {
             info: '=fo'
             },
      templateUrl: 'homeDirective.html'
          }

 scotchApp.controller('MyFormCtrl', [function() {

      this.user = {
                  name: '',
                  email: ''
                 };

      this.register = function() {
          // console.log('User clicked register', this.user);
           alert(this.user.name + "-- " + this.user.email);
          $scope.name = this.user.name;
       };
     }]);
   })
```

how can i make possible this when someone submit the form the about page is displayed after clicking submit button and all form data i want to display there.
here is my **plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/D5S2c6rgycWFfsyfhN9J?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So based off of what you put into plunker and looking at your code I noticed a few issues.

First: You had your controller inside your directive causing none of the code within the directive to be run.

Your Code

```
       var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp');
       scotchApp.directive('homeData', function() {
       return {
            scope:{
              info:'=fo'
            },
         templateUrl: 'homeDirective.html'
        }
         scotchApp.controller('MyFormCtrl', [function() {

          this.user = {
                name: '',
              email: ''
            };

          this.register = function() {
          // console.log('User clicked register', this.user);
              alert(this.user.name+ "-- " +this.user.email);
          $scope.name=this.user.name;
          };
          }]);
       })
```

Update Code:

```
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp');
       scotchApp.directive('homeData', function() {
       return {
            scope:{
              info:'=fo'
            },
         templateUrl: 'homeDirective.html'
        };

          });
          scotchApp.controller('MyFormCtrl', [function() {

          this.user = {
                name: '',
              email: ''
            };

          this.register = function() {
          // console.log('User clicked register', this.user);
              alert(this.user.name+ "-- " +this.user.email);
          $scope.name=this.user.name;
          };
          }]);
```

Second: You need to add some way allowing your variables to talk between controllers. I used a service and passed it into both controllers

### homeDirective.js

```
scotchApp.controller('MyFormCtrl', ['$scope', 'userService', function($scope, userService) {
         $scope.userService = userService;
          $scope.user = {
                name: '',
              email: ''
            };

          $scope.register = function() {
              //sets the variables within the service
              $scope.userService.setUserName($scope.user.name);
              $scope.userService.setUserEmail($scope.user.email);
              alert($scope.userService.getUserName() + "-- " + $scope.userService.getUserEmail());
          };
          }]);
          //Service to be passes to the controllers
          scotchApp.service('userService', function(){
            var userService = {
              user: {
                'name': '',
                'email': ''
              },
              getUser: function(){
                return userService.user;
              },
              getUserName: function(){
                return userService.user.name;
              },
              getUserEmail: function(){
                return userService.user.email;
              },
              setUserName: function(name){
                userService.user.name = name;
              },
              setUserEmail: function(email){
                userService.user.email = email;
              },
            };
            return userService;

          });
```

### script.js

```
scotchApp.controller('aboutController', ['$scope', 'userService', function($scope, userService) { 
               $scope.userService = userService;
               $scope.user = $scope.userService.user; 
               $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.'; 
           }]);
```

Third: Your HTML page had to be able to call the register function and move over to the about page.

### homeDirective.html

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center" >
  <h1>Home Page</h1>
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="MyFormCtrl as ctrl">
    Name: <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name">
    Email: <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email">
    <br/>
    <a type="submit" ng-href="#about">
      <button ng-click="register();" type="submit">Register</button>
    </a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Last: You should put your whole angular app in a self calling function like so

```
(function(){
     var app = angular.module('app'[]);
     //more code
})();
```

Here is the link to the plunk fork that I did for your code. Hopefully that all made sense.[Link to Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YKAX9BpLDYw3BJvQ2yEq?p=preview)

Good Luck!

Comment: @danial can we use isolated scope as well in homeData directive?

Comment: So 'userService' is the isolated scope that is passed to other scopes. It has all it's variables contained within itself and uses methods to manipulate those variables. If you wanted you could make an array called users within the service and allow for multiple users to be added or you could keep it isolated to one user. But this allows for you to call all of the user/s data throughout the lifespan of the application as long as you pass it into your directives and/or controlelrs.

Comment: @Danial thanks but i am talking about simple isolated scope directive could we make this result using that one like add return {
                scope:{
                  info:'=fo'
                } to directive for form and not use any service?

Comment: @Hassan So the problem with that is that you have your about page in a controller that has no access to that variable (without a service or rootScope access). you have to pass it in some way. Your directive has access to it and anything with access to the applications scope has access to it, but the scope of the about page controller is different than the scope of the directive. you need some way of communicating the two together otherwise when the about page is looking for your user object it won't find it because it is undefined in your about page scope.

Comment: @Hassan to add onto what I was ranting on if the directive was under the scope of the  about page  controller then it could work.

Comment: Awesome solution

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular [Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) to share data between controllers.You can use services to organize and share code across your app.

Comment: is it possible without service ,if we can use only one controller for directive ?

Comment: You can use `$rootScope` then.

Comment: But make controller for about page, as you need it on about page. It is good practice to make seperate controller for each page.And share data through services.